# Instantiate the field of an Automatic propertiy automatically in C#

Tags: c#, properties

this is my Model:

```
public class Schoolclass
{
    private List<Pupil> _pupils;

    public Schoolclass()
    {
        _pupils = new List<Pupil>();
    }            

    public int SchoolclassId { get; set; }
    public string SchoolclassCode { get; set; }


    public List<Pupil> Pupils
    {
        get { return _pupils;} 
        set { _pupils = value; }
    }        
}
```

Can I do this somehow with C# only without 3rd-party tools:

```
[Initialize]
public List<Pupil> Pupils {get;set}
```

I want that C# generates the field _pupils automatically.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no automatic way, but you can still assign the property in the constructor:

```
public Schoolclass()
{
    Pupils = new List<Pupil>();
}
```

Also, since `Pupils` is a collection, I would suggest making it read-only:

```
public List<Pupil> Pupils {get; private set;}
```

**Update**
Full class would look like so:

```
public class Schoolclass
{
    public Schoolclass()
    {
        Pupils = new List<Pupil>();
    }            

    public int SchoolclassId { get; set; }
    public string SchoolclassCode { get; set; }
    public List<Pupil> Pupils { get; private set; }

}
```

Comment: to prevent misunderstandings can you post the full code please?

Comment: so judging his update now, I do not need the single field _pupils? ok Works!

Comment: @Lisa: just for being complete, I update the answer with the full reworked class.

Comment: yes thanks Frederik I already tried your code as I said before it works fine! :)

Comment: @FredrikMörk - I was intrigued by the side comment *Also, since `Pupils` is a collection, I would suggest making it read-only*. I didn't challenge it but wondered why. It wasn't the topic of OP's question, but this link expands on reasoning for future readers: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182327(v=vs.110).aspx  Thanks.

Comment: @atconway: in addition to what is mentioned in the article you linked it also makes it less needed to null check collection properties. When the code is designed so that collection properties are read-only and assigned during object construction, you can safely go ahead and check the Count property or iterate over the collection without needing to sprinkle your code with null checks.